# Automatically play the video like in Facebook using AVPlayer in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, avplayer

I am trying to play video like in facebook automatically without clicking on the video. I searched on the stackoverflow but came up with the following codes for playing with AVPlayer. But it didn't work out. Please help me to sort out this in swift 3?

Comment: What is the issue ?

Comment: It doesn't show the video in the view. @Sandeep Bhandari